# How to create spark dataframe with none/null value?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to initialize a dataframe where some rows have None/Null value in spark scala(version 3.2.1).
How to do this ?

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  Seq((0, "a", true), (1, "b", true), (2, "c", false), (3, "a", false), (4, "a", None), (5, "c", false))
).toDF("id", "category1", "category2")
df.show()
```

I get this error:

> UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Any is not supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the nearest supertype of both `Boolean` and `Option[Nothing] (None)` is `Any`, and spark doesn't support that. The only thing you need to do to make your code work is to wrap the booleans inside Option/Some, so there's no need to define struct types, spark can figure it out. This would work:

```scala
Seq((0, "a", Some(true)), (1, "b", Some(true)), (2, "c", Some(false)), (3, "a", Some(false)), (4, "a", None), (5, "c", Some(false)))
  .toDF("id", "category1", "category2")
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve your required output using following code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, BooleanType};

val data = Seq(Row(true), Row(null))
val schema = List(StructField("boolColName", BooleanType, true))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data), StructType(schema))
df.show()
```

The true supplied to *schema* specifies if the column is nullable